# JavaScript RegEx.test() conditional aborts/returns function early

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, submit

I have a simple class project where i'm doing some form validation. We have to use some basic regex expressions to validate input. I have this code in an external js file.

I have a function that captures the onsubmit event, and returns the value of the validation function of whether or not to proceed with the postback.

The problem is when i call the RegEx.test() method my validation functions stops and returns, and the postback proceeds inadvertently. Also strangly if i create a regex object using the "new RegEx()" the same thing happens. I'm lost as to why.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // onsubmit event    
    $('form').submit(
        function() {
            return validation();
        }
        );

    // form validation
    function validation() {

        resetErrors();

        //variables
        var validates = true;
        var errorString = "";
        //var isEmail = new RegEx('^.+@.+\..+$'); // function stops here if line is uncommented and kicks off the postback?
        //alert("harro new regex?"); // does not run if above line is uncommented


        var isEmail = "/^.+@.+\..+$/"; // this doesn't stop the function
        alert("harro isEmail direct regex string assignment"); // runs

        var isZipCode = "/^(\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/"; // this doesn't stop the function
        alert("harro isZipCode direct regex string assignment"); // runs

        //firstname
        if (!$('#firstName').val().trim()) {
            validates = false;
            $('#firstName').addClass('error');
            errorString += "First Name is blank. <br />";
        }
        //lastname
        if (!$('#lastName').val().trim()) {
            validates = false;
            $('#lastName').addClass('error');
            errorString += "Last Name is blank. <br />";
        }
        //email
        if (!$('#email').val().trim()) {
            validates = false;
            errorString += "Email is blank. <br />";
            $('#email').addClass('error');
        }
        // if this runs the test, the function stops here
        else if (!isEmail.test(email.value)) {
            validates = false;
            errorString += "Please enter a valid email address. <br />";
            $('#email').addClass('error');
        }
        alert("harro rest of function after email test?")// does not run if "else if" is ran

        //address
        if (!$('#address').val().trim()) {
            validates = false;
            $('#address').addClass('error');
            errorString += "Address is blank. <br />";
        }

        //zipcode
        if (!$('#zipCode').val().trim()) {
            validates = false;
            $('#zipCode').addClass('error');
            errorString += "Zipcode is blank. <br />";
        }
        // if this runs the test, the function stops here
        else if (!isZipCode.test(zipCode.value)) {
            validates = false;
            $('#zipCode').addClass('error');
            errorString += "Please enter a valide zip code. <br />";
        }
        alert("harro rest of function after zipcide test?")// does not run if "else if" is ran


        if (validates) {
            return true;
        }

        //output error messages
        $('#pageTitle').after("<p id='errorText'>" + errorString + "</p>");

        return false;
    }

    //reset validation errors
    function resetErrors() {

        $('#errorText').remove();
        $('#firstName').removeClass('error');
        $('#lastName').removeClass('error');
        $('#email').removeClass('error');
        $('#address').removeClass('error');
        $('#zipCode').removeClass('error');

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Using the properly spelled RegExp makes the test work and not abort! So i can just assign the regexp variable that way. However, i am curious why i can't create the regexp variable by just assigning it the regexp string. I've seen several tutorials do it that way. When i do it that way, it still aborts on the test.

Comment: what do you mean by "just assigning it the regex string"?

Comment: In JavaScript, you can create a regex object in two ways: Using a regex literal `/.*/` or a `RegExp` constructor `new RegExp('.*')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are missing a "p", it's **RegExp** not RegEx

```
var isEmail = new RegExp('^.+@.+\..+$');
```

But in general with these problems, just have Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools open (F12 in windows) and then you will see the cause of the error. If you write **new Regex()** in the console, it will tell you that **Regex is not defined**, if you start writing RegE..., it will autocomplete it for you to RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

You might check your JavaScript console for error messages. These might lead you to using RegExp instead of RegEx !!